# Writing a function that is polymorphic over lenses for a given datatype?

Tags: haskell, lenses

Not sure if I'm phrasing the question correctly in the title but I'm trying to do something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

module Lib where

import Control.Lens 


data Foo = Foo {_bar1 :: Int
               ,_bar2 :: String
               ,_bar3 :: [Rational]} deriving (Show, Eq)
makeFieldsNoPrefix ''Foo

aFoo :: Foo
aFoo = Foo 33 "Hm?" [1/6,1/7,1/8]


stringToLens :: (HasBar1 s a, Functor f, HasBar2 s a, HasBar3 s a) => String -> Maybe ((a -> f a) -> s -> f s)
stringToLens str = case str of
    "bar1" -> Just  bar1
    "bar2" -> Just  bar2
    "bar3" -> Just  bar3
    _      -> Nothing 

updateFoo :: (HasBar1 a1 a2, HasBar2 a1 a2, HasBar3 a1 a2, Read a2) => String -> String -> a1 -> Maybe a1
updateFoo lensStr valStr myFoo = case stringToLens lensStr of
    Just aLens ->  Just $ set aLens (read valStr) myFoo
    Nothing    -> Nothing 

newFoo :: Maybe Foo
newFoo = updateFoo "bar1" 22 aFoo  
{-- 
Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Int’
    arising from a functional dependency between:
      constraint ‘HasBar2 Foo Int’ arising from a use of ‘updateFoo’
      instance ‘HasBar2 Foo String’
        at /home/gnumonic/Haskell/Test/test/src/Lib.hs:14:1-24
• In the expression: updateFoo "bar1" 22 aFoo
  In an equation for ‘newFoo’: newFoo = updateFoo "bar1" 22 aFoo 
  --}
```

(Ignore the use of read here, I do it the "right way" in the actual module I'm working on.)

That, obviously, doesn't work. I thought that making a typeclass along the lines of this might work:

```
class OfFoo s a where
  ofFoo :: s -> a

instance OfFoo Foo Int where
  ofFoo foo = foo ^. bar1 

instance OfFoo Foo String where
  ofFoo foo = foo ^. bar2

instance OfFoo Foo [Rational] where
  ofFoo foo = foo ^. bar3
```

But there doesn't seem to be a way of adding that class to the constraint in such a way that the stringToLens function is actually usable, even though it typechecks fine until I try to use it. (Although it doesn't even typecheck if I use makeLenses instead of makeFields, and I'm not really sure why.)

E.g. (with the maybe removed for simplicity):

```
stringToLens :: (HasBar1 s a, Functor f, HasBar2 s a, HasBar3 s a, OfFoo s a) => String -> (a -> f a) -> s -> f s
stringToLens str = case str of
    "bar1" -> bar1
    "bar2" ->  bar2
    "bar3" ->  bar3
```

That typechecks but is pretty much useless, since any attempt to apply the function throws the functional dependency error.

I also tried using the Reified newtypes from Control.Lens.Reify, but that didn't fix the functional dependency issue.

What I can't figure out is that if I modify the `updateFoo` like so:

```
updateFoo2 :: Read a => ASetter Foo Foo a a -> String -> Foo -> Foo
updateFoo2 aLens val myFoo = set aLens (read val) myFoo
```

Then this works:

```
testFunc :: Foo
testFunc = updateFoo2 bar1 "22" aFoo
```

But this throws the functional dependency error at `myLens1` whenever it's used (although the definition typechecks):

```
testFunc' :: Foo
testFunc' = updateFoo2 (stringToLens "bar1") 22 aFoo -- Error on (stringToLens "bar1")

myLens1 :: (HasBar1 s a, Functor f, HasBar2 s a, HasBar3 s a, OfFoo s a) => (a -> f a) -> s -> f s
myLens1 = stringToLens "bar1" -- typechecks

testFunc2 :: Foo
testFunc2 = updateFoo2 myLens1 "22" aFoo   -- Error on myLens1
```

So I can define a stringToLens function, but it's pretty much useless...

Unfortunately I wrote a bunch of code on the assumption that *something* like this could be made to work. I'm writing a packet generator, and if I can get this to work then I have a pretty convenient way of quickly adding support for new protocols. (The rest of my code extensively uses lenses for a variety of purposes.) I can think of a few workarounds but they're all extremely verbose and require either a lot of template Haskell (to generate a copy of every function for each new protocol data type) or a lot of boilerplate (i.e. creating dummy types to signal the correct type for `read` in the `updateFoo` functions).

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do here with lenses, or is it just impossible without something like impredicative types? If not, is there a better workaround the the one's I'm seeing?

At this point my best guess is that there's just not enough information for the compiler to infer the type of the value string without having a fully evaluated lens.

But it seems like something along these lines *should* be possible, since by the time the output of stringToLens is passed to updateFoo, it will have a definite (and correct) type. So I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing `stringToLens` would require something like dependent types, because the *type* of the resulting `Lens` depends on an argument's *value*: the field name. Haskell doesn't have full dependent types, although they can be [emulated](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) with more or less difficulty.

In `updateFoo`, you take as parameter both the field name (`lensStr`) and the "serialized"  form of the field's value (`valStr`), and return an update function for some datatype. Can we have that without getting dependent-ish?

Imagine that, for a certain type `Foo`, you had something like a `Map FieldName (String -> Maybe (Foo -> Foo))`. For each field name, you would have a function that parsed the field's value and, if successful, returned an update function for `Foo`. No dependent types would be required, as the parsing of each field's value would be hidden behind functions with a uniform signature.

How to build such map-of-parsers-returning-updaters for a given type? You could build it manually, or it could be derived with the help of some [generics](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html) [wizardry](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop).

---

Here's a possible implementation based on the [red-black-record](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/red-black-record) library (although it would be better to base it on the more established [generics-sop](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop)). Some preliminary imports:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances, #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map
import Data.Map.Strict
import Data.Monoid (Endo (..))
import Data.Proxy
import Data.RBR
  ( (:.:) (Comp),
    And,
    Case (..),
    FromRecord (fromRecord),
    I (..),
    IsRecordType,
    K (..),
    KeyValueConstraints,
    KeysValuesAll,
    Maplike,
    Record,
    ToRecord (toRecord),
    collapse'_Record,
    cpure'_Record,
    injections_Record,
    liftA2_Record,
    unI,
  )
import GHC.Generics (Generic)
import GHC.TypeLits
```

The implementation itself:

```
type FieldName = String

type TextInput = String

makeUpdaters ::
  forall r c.
  ( IsRecordType r c, -- Is r convertible to the rep used by red-black-record?
    Maplike c, -- Required for certain applicative-like operations over the rep.
    KeysValuesAll (KeyValueConstraints KnownSymbol Read) c -- Are all fields readable?
  ) =>
  Proxy r ->
  Map FieldName (TextInput -> Maybe (r -> r))
makeUpdaters _ =
  let parserForField :: forall v. Read v 
                     => FieldName -> ((,) FieldName :.: (->) TextInput :.: Maybe) v
      parserForField fieldName = Comp (fieldName, Comp read)
      parserRecord = cpure'_Record (Proxy @Read) parserForField
      injectParseResult ::
        forall c a.
        Case I (Endo (Record I c)) a -> -- injection into the record
        ((,) FieldName :.: (->) TextInput :.: Maybe) a -> -- parsing function
        (FieldName, Case I (Maybe (Endo (Record I c))) TextInput) 
      injectParseResult (Case makeUpdater) (Comp (fieldName, Comp readFunc)) =
        ( fieldName,
          ( Case $ \textInput ->
              let parsedFieldValue = readFunc . unI $ textInput
               in case parsedFieldValue of
                    Just x -> Just $ makeUpdater . pure $ x
                    Nothing -> Nothing ) )
      collapsed :: [(FieldName, Case I (Maybe (Endo (Record I c))) TextInput)]
      collapsed = collapse'_Record $
          liftA2_Record
            (\injection parser -> K [injectParseResult injection parser])
            injections_Record
            parserRecord
      toFunction :: Case I (Maybe (Endo (Record I c))) TextInput 
                 -> TextInput -> Maybe (r -> r)
      toFunction (Case f) textInput = case f $ I textInput of
        Just (Endo endo) -> Just $ fromRecord . endo . toRecord
        Nothing -> Nothing
   in toFunction <$> Map.fromList collapsed
```

A type in which to test it:

```
data Person = Person {name :: String, age :: Int} deriving (Generic, Show)
-- let updaters = makeUpdaters (Proxy @Person)
--
instance ToRecord Person

instance FromRecord Person
```

Comment: I missed your updated reply and I've been struggling with Generics-SOP since I posted the question. I managed to implement the equivalent of "set" alright with that library (which does what I was trying to do when I posted the question, at least)  but I've been going insane trying to figure out how to extract a value from an N-ary product for a few days now. (Turns out it would be pretty helpful to have a function like 'viewFoo' too).

Anyway thanks for the example and the reference to that library. Hopefully I won't struggle with that as much as with generics-sop.

Comment: Oh, just to elaborate on my problem in case there's a simple solution: It was easy to find a way to extract the first value from an NP with `go (x :* xs) = x :* Nil ::  (xs ~ (b ': bs)) => NP I xs -> NP I '[b]` (can then "unwrap" the result), but it seems *impossible* to write a function that recurses through an arbitrarily large NP and spits out the Nth result, since there's no way to get out of the `Could not deduce x ~ bN`. (Where x is the output type of the function and `bN` is the type of the value at the nth position of the index list). Tried to make a bunch of constraints, none worked.